# Toric decomposition of multipartitions

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, partitions, toric-varieties

Fix $k \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$. By a $k$-multipartition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$ of $N$, I mean that each $\lambda_i$ is a partition of some $N_i$ and $\sum N_i = N$.

Let's call $\lambda$ *admissible* if  $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ for $i \neq j$, and furthermore define $\lambda$ to be *toric* if $\lambda_i$ is a partition of $i$ (in particular toric implies admissible).

Associate to such $\lambda$ the Young diagram $Y_\lambda=\sum Y_{\lambda_i}$ obtained by placing all Young diagrams $Y_{\lambda_i}$ on top of one another, and arranging the rows in correct order.

At last, we say that *the pair $(\lambda,\tau)$ of multipartitions is admissible* if $\lambda$ is admissible, $\tau$ is toric and each Young diagram satisfies $Y_{\lambda_i} \subseteq Y_{\tau_i}$, with $Y_{\lambda_i}$ having the same number of rows as $Y_{\tau_i}$

**Question 1** Given an admissible pair $(\lambda,\tau)$, when does there exist admissible pairs $(\lambda^{(1)},\tau^{(1)}),\dots, (\lambda^{(r)},\tau^{(r)})$ with $(\lambda^{(i)},\tau^{(i)}) \neq (\lambda^{(j)},\tau^{(j)})$ for all $i \neq j$ such that
$$ \sum_i a_i Y_{\lambda^{(i)}} = (\sum_i a_i) Y_{\lambda} \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_i a_i Y_{\tau^{(i)}} = (\sum_i a_i) Y_{\tau}$$

**Notes** The toric condition fixes $N=1 + \dots + k$. The questions comes from determining whether such an admissible pair $(\lambda,\tau)$ would be a vertex of a certain Newton Polyhedron.

**Examples** I will denote partitions (since they are small) simply as a sequence of numbers, and I will omit the Young-diagram notation.
\begin{gather}
\lambda=(1,2,3,12,23), \tau=(1,2,3,13,23); \\ 
\lambda^{(1)} = (1,2,3,12,22), \tau^{(1)}= (1,2,3,13,23); \\ 
\lambda^{(2)} = (1,2,3,13,23), \tau^{(2)}= (1,2,3,13,23)
\end{gather}
satisfy
$$ 2(\lambda,\tau) =1 (\lambda^{(1)},\tau^{(1)}) + 1 (\lambda^{(2)},\tau^{(2)}).$$
Another example is
\begin{gather}
\lambda=(1,2,3,12,13), \tau_0=(1,2,3,13,14); \\
 \lambda^{(1)} = (1,2,3,12,23), \tau^{(1)}= (1,2,3,13,23); \\
 \lambda^{(2)} = (1,11,2,3,13), \tau^{(2)}= (1,11,3,4,14),
\end{gather}
which satisfy the same equation
$$ 2(\lambda,\tau) =1 (\lambda^{(1)},\tau^{(1)}) + 1 (\lambda^{(2)},\tau^{(2)}).$$

**Question 2** In the case that the assertion in Question 1 holds for $r >1$, is it then always the case that $r=2$, when it is assumed that $gcd(a_1,\dots,a_r)=1$, and that no proper subset of the admissible pairs $(\lambda^{(1)},\tau^{(1)}),\dots, (\lambda^{(r)},\tau^{(r)})$ satisfy such relations with the pair $(\lambda,\tau)$?

**EDIT**: I have added the condition $(\lambda^{(i)},\tau^{(i)}) \neq (\lambda^{(j)},\tau^{(j)})$ for all $i \neq j$, since such equality would yield an immediate reduction of the equation in Question 1.

**EDIT 2**: I have added the condition in Question 2 that $r > 1$ (since otherwise two expressions correspond to the same point in the embedding space of the Newton polygon). Furthermore, I have added the condition that the expressions are "minimal" (see question 2). If the expressions are not minimal, it means merely that geometrically the pair $(\lambda,\tau)$ is a convex combination of fewer points $(\lambda^{(i)},\tau^{(i)})$.

Comment: The answer to question 2 is trivially "No", because $\lambda_i = \lambda_0$, $\tau_i = \tau_0$ will work. I assume you intend a non-equality restriction, but since the examples have $\tau_i = \tau_0$ I'm not sure whether you want to require all of the $\lambda_i$ to be distinct or all of the pairs $(\lambda_i, \tau_i)$ to be distinct.

Comment: @Peter Good point. In essence, I certainly don't want to allow $(\lambda_i,\tau_i) = (\lambda_0,\tau_0)$, since this would immediately just give rise to a reduction (by division) in the formula of Q1. I will edit.
Also there was a typo in $\tau_0$ and $\tau_2$ of example 2, which are now fixed. Thank you!

Comment: For the most part, there are multiple solutions with $r = 1$ which can then be combined linearly.

Comment: @Peter Again you are correct! I will edit to explain why both situations are not so interesting for me: In essence, I want to consider "minimal solutions" for Q2 with $r \neq 1$ due to the toric geometry

Comment: While you're editing, could you tweak the notation? At present $\lambda_1$ means one thing in the first paragraph and something different further down. Perhaps use $(\lambda, \tau)$ for the goal pair of question 1 and $(\lambda', \tau'), \ldots, (\lambda^{(r)}, \tau^{(r)})$ for the other pairs?

Comment: @Peter Of course. I did this now, and hope that every part was changed accordingly. And thank you for your interest!